# Enable custom errors for azure websites

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, remote-debugging

What are the steps neccessary to enable custom errors for azure websites.

I have set the 'custom errors' xml tag to 'off', yet that still does not work and i am still getting nonsense generic 500 page.

```
 <customErrors mode="Off">

    </customErrors>
```

theres the 'remote debugging option' that allows me to select a visual studio version.Could that be it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzLco.png)

Answer (score 1):

That's the correct way to turn off custom errors. However, that will only be effective if the requests actually reach your site. In some situation, the requests don't make it that far, at which point you lose control over custom errors. For example, if your site is stopped, or you have a free/shared site that ran out of quota, you won't be able to turn off custom errors.

Two suggestions:

- clarify your question to specify exactly what error you are getting and in what situation
- Practice turning off custom errors on a test site that's in a clean state, to isolate from the specific issue your site may be having.